# Implication of P =NP on video games?

Tags: computational-complexity

I was wondering if NP problems were actually solvable in P time, then what will be the impact on Video Games, if any ?

Comment: In case you are talking about *video games* then for that, $NP$ problems *are* solved in polynomial time, approximations are enough.

Comment: The above is assuming that you are talking about the code behind running an AI system, or whatever. If not, then I am not really sure what you're asking about.

Comment: I was wondering if it would impact the process of creating a world or an environment ?

Comment: Are you referring to rendering the images/calculation in the physics engine? In that case, we have *very* efficient approximation algorithms.

Comment: It has been shown that in general, [sokoban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) and [Minesweeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_%28video_game%29) are NP-complete.

Comment: @MJD just because a *computer* can't beat it efficiently, doesn't mean I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether or not they also developed an effective algorithm for solving some NP-complete problems. Just knowing that the two classes are related doesn't necessarily tell you how to solve it in P time.

And being able to solve something in polynomial time doesn't mean that you can solve it very quickly: If the running time of the algorithm is n^3 * one googleplex, it's still polynomial time but probably not practically solvable.

And anyway, the only problem that I know of that is NP-complete that is remotely related to video games is the Travelling salesman problem, so better pathfinding algorithms?

So in short, I doubt it would have much impact. Though it does very much depend on HOW it is proven. Since our current methods don't seem to work, a proof would most likely be a great leap forward in mathematics, provided it was a proof method that could be applied to other problems.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148836/what-would-be-the-impact-of-p-np

A similar question on another stack exchange which probably answers your question better.